# Looking for a movie with old man who was a robot/android and was recharging under stairs

Tags: story-identification, androids, cyborg

This was a foreign movie or maybe a TV episode (German, possibly).

I remember an old man in a house who was a robot/android and he was going under the stairs to recharge. He turned a handle/knob on banister to get under the stairs and he was recharging there sitting, if I remember rightly.

IMDB is useless and I have no idea if it was from 80's or 90's.